# The fearsome maiden

Tags: rhyme, anagram

> Fair maiden of ___, most feared in these parts,
> with terrible power thou ___ men's hearts.
> The beaux of all kingdoms thou ___ to doom;
> thy ___ and light they seek, but find their tomb.
> Excited, the ___ all play, sing and dance;
> each soldier and ___ falls under your trance.
> The suitors all ___ with armor and swords;
> a ___ for thee, each of peasants and lords.
> In duels or ___ the smitten men brawl;
> for each the ___ is the same: They all fall.

Fill the gaps with ten different anagrams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the blanks are

> ULSTER, RULEST, LUREST, LUSTRE, LUTERS, SUTLER, RUSTLE, LUSTER, TRUELS, RESULT

but I am not very convinced by the eighth because the sentence structure comes out rather weird. I should mention that a

> SUTLER is someone who follows an army around and provides them with provisions.

Here's the whole thing with the blanks filled in.

> Fair maiden of ULSTER, most feared in these parts,
> with terrible power thou RULEST men's hearts.
> The beaux of all kingdoms thou LUREST to doom;
> thy LUSTRE and light they seek, but find their tomb.
> Excited, the LUTERS all play, sing and dance;
> each soldier and SUTLER falls under your trance.
> The suitors all RUSTLE with armor and swords;
> a LUSTER for thee, each of peasants and lords.
> In duels or TRUELS the smitten men brawl;
> for each the RESULT is the same: They all fall.

Comment: This is correct. I had a couple of variants for line 8 but neither sounded particularly natural when the blanked word has to be in the singular...

Comment: Nice work! I got stuck on truels, never heard of that!

Comment: Yeah, I can well believe that cramming all those words in made it pretty impossible to avoid some inelegance :-).

Comment: @Amoz Heh. That word was the one that got me in, so to speak.

Comment: (More precisely, I thought about possibilities for the last line and noticed that one was an anagram of that.)

Comment: How about "Each peasant thy \_\_\_, and each of the lords" for line 8? I'm not sure whether it's any better than what's there at present. Or "A \_\_\_ for thee, every one of the lords" but I think that fails semantically because the point is that it covers _everyone_, not just one class.

Comment: Ahh right, putting the blanked word in the middle could have been a better option. Also the 6th word is probably an anachronism in a medieval context but I really didn't want to leave it out :)